# How do I make it so that brush stroke is part of mask?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, mask, clipping-mask

This is probably an easy thing to answer but I'm trying to make a simple image mask with a brush stroke type mask

I have a basic shape with a artistic brush stroke:

[image]

But when I try Object > Clipping Mask > Make the stroke is ignored and only the shape is use as the mask:

[image]

I want the mask to have a brush stroke edge, if that makes sense.

I've tried the the various Pathfinder options but it doesn't seem to make a difference. I'm using Illustrator 5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stroke is dynamic and not a part of the shape itself. One solution could be to do the following:

- Use *Object > Expand Appearance* to convert the stroke to paths.
- Use *Pathfinder > Unite* to unite the original shape with the stroke.
- Use *Object > Compound Path > Make* to convert all the individual smaller paths into one compund path.
- Select the path and the image and use *Object > Clipping Mask > Make* to create the clipping mask.

[image]

Comment: Spot on, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way to do this *without having to expand your shapes:*

---

**Use Opacity Masks.**

Similar to the way Masking works in Photoshop, you can define the visibility of objects by using the colours black or white (and every shade in-between!!).
In Illustrator each object – in your case a placed image – can have its own Opacity Mask:

1. Place your image.
2. In the `Appearance` Panel select `Opacity` and hit `Make Mask`.

[image: Opacity Dialogue]

3. Now select the newly created all black Mask in the Dialog.
4. Now you can add any object/shape (make sure it is white) to create a knockout in the mask.
5. After you have finished creating your mask, you'll have to open the opacity dialogue again to return to the "normal" world where you can edit your document as usual.

[image: opacity mask]

---

**This method is rather obscure, but it has does some advantages:**

• keep masking shapes live to easily edit them.

• less path points when working with complex shapes like grunge
brushes etc.

• using grey values you can partially mask things

**There are however also disadvantages:**

• The functionality is not very intuitive as it is hidden inside the opacity dialogue at object -level

• while working on the opacity masks you enter into a *stranger-thingsesque alternate editing mode* with no clear indication on how to get back to the *normal mode.*